# Importing Dates/Time from Excel to a Sharepoint list using Power Automate

Tags: date, sharepoint, time, power-automate, sharepoint-list

I'm hoping somebody can shed some light on this issue. I am trying to build a flow that adds new entries/updates existing entries in a SP list based on an Excel Spreadsheet stored on OneDrive. The spreadsheet contains both columns with dates and date & time.
I've researched this extensively, trying to get the dates properly transferred into SP. The common solution is to use an expression AddDays (for dates) and AddSeconds (for time), as per tutorials [here](https://normyoung.ca/2020/07/20/import-excel-data-into-an-existing-sharepoint-list-using-power-automate/) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6Sn0RZNfyA).

However, these methods require the dates and time to be passed as numerical values (integers and float respectively) from Excel. It appears that the Excel Online connector only passes those values as string. As discussed in [this thread](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Excel-dates-turned-into-integers/td-p/130364), this used to work with the standard Excel connector, but this connector got deprecated. I'm hoping somebody has a workaround or solution. Thank you!

*Update:* As the SP list expects the date time as string, I've also tried to convert the dates & time columns to text in Excel, using the Text function. It worked for transferring the dates, but the time values are inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

Declare two variables

1. **StringDate** Type: String
2. **StrToInt** Type: Integer

[image: Variables]

Now set "StringDate" to your Excel value. (Please keep in mind I am using an Apply to Each to get the Excel value)

[image: String Date Value]

Now convert "StringDate" to an integer with "
StrToInt" and Decrement "StrToInt" by 1.

```
@{int(variables('StringDate'))}
```

[image: String to Integer]

Now add the integer to SharePoint and convert it to a date.

```
@{addDays('1899-12-31',int(variables('StrToInt')),'yyyy-MM-dd')}
```

[image]